# Could non-continuous sequence of functions converge uniformly to non-continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I know there is a non-continuous sequence of functions $f_n(x)$ which is converge uniformly to a continuous function $f(x)$

My question if there exist a non-continuous sequence of functions $f_n(x)$ that converge uniformly to non-continuous function $f(x)$ ?

Comment: Take $f_n(x)=f(x)$ for some discontinuous function $f(x)$

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Take for example $f_n(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor+\frac{1}{n}$ which converge uniformly to $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$. Actually you can take any not-continuous function $f$, any sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that $a_n\to 0$ and let $f_n=f+a_n$.

Comment: I was thinking how it uniformly converges?

Comment: @BAYMAX Well $\sup_x|f_n(x)-f(x)|=1/n\to 0$

Comment: Great!! that's nice!